# Why am I getting arrayindexoutofboundsexception?

Tags: android, andengine, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using AndEngine to make a game and I have no idea why I'm getting this error. It seemed to work before and I'm not sure of what code changes caused the error. Anyone have any ideas?

```
    07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at com.prattia.webs.testgfx5.TestGFX5Activity$2.onAreaTouched(TestGFX5Activity.java:249)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onAreaTouchEvent(Scene.java:409)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onSceneTouchEvent(Scene.java:328)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouchScene(Engine.java:452)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouchEvent(Engine.java:438)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController$TouchEventRunnablePoolItem.run(BaseTouchController.java:102)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.onHandlePoolItem(RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.java:54)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.onHandlePoolItem(RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.java:1)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler.onUpdate(PoolUpdateHandler.java:88)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController.onUpdate(BaseTouchController.java:62)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:584)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
07-02 01:34:44.747: E/AndroidRuntime(19252):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
```

And that section of my code:

```
private void createFiller(float x, float y) {
        fillerNum++;
        Log.e("Creating Filler",Integer.toString(fillerNum));
        filler[fillerNum].active=true;
        filler[fillerNum].sprite = new Sprite(x-fillerTR.getWidth()/2,y - fillerTR.getHeight()/2,fillerTR,getVertexBufferObjectManager())
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY){
                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()){
                    setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - getHeight() / 2);
                }
                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
                    Log.e("Action Up",Integer.toString(fillerNum));
                    if(!filler[fillerNum].body.getUserData().equals("destroyed"))//Line 249
                        createStationaryFiller();
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        scene.registerTouchArea(filler[fillerNum].sprite);

        filler[fillerNum].body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, filler[fillerNum].sprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        filler[fillerNum].body.setUserData("fill");
        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(filler[fillerNum].sprite, filler[fillerNum].body, true, true));
        scene.attachChild(filler[fillerNum].sprite);
    }
```

If there is any other explanation or code needed, let me know and I can post it. I'm stumped!!

Comment: As per error description you are accessing an array element at *index* whose value is either equal to or greater than the length of an array.

Comment: I guess `fillerNum` is greater or equal to `filler.length`.

Comment: "private void createFiller(float x, float y) { fillerNum++;" incrementing the counter at the beginning of the method? Looks problematic to me. But without seeing the rest of the code for that area, one can only guess...

Comment: @Cruceo you were right. My very last incrementation happened to exceed the limit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Line numbers would be nice, but I suspect that fillerNum is larger than the size of your filler array.
Anyway, your stack trace says the exception is thrown in line 249, so find that line and you'll find your problem :)

Comment: so yeah, just like Harry Joy and I pointed out, the size of your array is probably less than `fillerNum`.